# Get Json object passed in $http.put request

Tags: angularjs, json, jetty, dropwizard

I am a newbie to angularjs. I am trying to send a json object in $http.put request as follows:

```
function LoginCtrl($http){
this.login = function(){
  var self = this;
        self.user = {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
        }
    $http.put('http://localhost:8086/app/login',self.user).then(function 
successCallback(response) {
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
      })
}
}
```

I just want to get this json object in Rest api, the code of which is as follows:
@Path("/app")
public class LoginResource {

```
public LoginResource() {
}

@PUT
@Path("/login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getUserByName() {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED).build();
}
```

What parameters i need to pass to this getUserByName api?. I am using dropwizard

Also if somebody could tell how to set the index.html page as the starting page in jetty server config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your Dropwizard(Jersey) backend define your input

```
public Response getUserByName(User user) { ...
```

Then you can map your JSON to an entity like this:

```
public class User {
   @JsonProperty("name") 
   private String name; }
```

In angularJS pass the Json object as a request payload in $http.PUT(uri,`<JsonObject>`)

Comment: In Backend I am using dropwizard

Comment: Then you should need @RequestBody annotation at all. in your request object you can use @JsonProperty("name") to map things togerer.

Comment: Actually I needed to get the request payload in my webmethod. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I got the answer, we just need to make a POJO class with the same names of variables as the JSON object's variables, and then pass that POJO object to Response.getUserByName

Comment: yes, you're right or you can annotate them like in an example above

Answer (score 0):

```
http.put(url, JSON.stringify(self.user), function (err, response) 
{
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: And how to get it in Response getUserByName ??

Comment: you mean after put u want to get records by http.get ?

Comment: after put request your data is updated in your database .So get request will pick updated data .     http.get(url, false, function (err, response) {    }

Comment: after put i want to get the passed user payload in the rest api